# Webpack: Uncaught ReferenceError: plural is not defined

Tags: jquery, webpack, webpack-2

I am using `webpack 3.2.0` and `jQuery 2.1.1` for my project.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack');

config = {
    // define entry point
    entry: "./src/index.js",

    // define output point
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, ''), // no need to create folder
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
              test: require.resolve('./jquery.min.js'),
              use: [{
                  loader: 'expose-loader',
                  options: 'jQuery'
              },{
                  loader: 'expose-loader',
                  options: '$'
              }]
          }]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Snippet of my javascript file

```
function plural(s) {
    "use strict";
    return s + 's';
}
```

But It gives below error in web browser.

```
(index):672 Uncaught ReferenceError: plural is not defined
    at buildPageElements ((index):672)
    at finishInitialization ((index):5113)
    at Object.<anonymous> ((index):5142)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

If I add `window.plural = plural` then It is working fine.

Is there any solution that I don't have to use `window.plural = plural` in my javascript file

Comment: Where/how are you importing `plural` into the module where it's used?

Comment: (You do know that it's much more complicated than just adding an `s` to the end of words...?)

Comment: This is one function of my javascript file. I am getting *not defined* error for all functions.

Comment: Again: Where/how are you importing `plural` into the module where you're getting that error? You certainly won't get it in the same module, if you try to use it in the same scope as that declaration or a nested scope. We can't help you with code we cannot see. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.